# @RequestBody return null after create body

Tags: java, request, okhttp

i have created `RequestBody` with Gson and add to `Post` request, but in the `controller` of api (url), all attrs return null.

- Add to `RequestBody`:

  ```
  MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  jsonObject.put("dataFromAppChinh", "demo thoi");
  jsonObject.put("path", path);
  String body = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
  RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(body, JSON);
  Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://" + path + "/api/startapp").post(requestBody).build();
  ```
- Controller

  ```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ChatBot {
    @PostMapping(value = "/startapp")
        @ResponseBody
        public Object start(@RequestBody() ChatBotResponse item) {
            try {
                item.setResponseList(startApp(item.getPath()));
                return item;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error(ex);
                return ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
  ```
- My `ChatBotResponse` POJO:

  ```
    @Data
    public class ChatBotResponse 
    {
        private String dataFromAppChinh;
        private String responseList;
        private String path;
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found problem is `gson.toJson(jsonObject)` insert `map` string before my `Json String`.
I changed to `jsonObject.toString()` and it worked.